# Python Django forms, form is not work with entered data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Im new with Django and Im trying to include my own form

My forms.py

```
class MyOwnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['username']
```

My views.py

```
def testing_Form(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        form = MyOwnForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            album = form.save(commit=False)
            album.user = request.user
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']

        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

my form.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'form_template.html' %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the last one form_template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I open the Form Webpage, I get a empty entry field and the submit button. But when I click this button. The page is reloading and nothing more.

what do i have to do that i can work with the entered data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I click this button. The page is reloading and nothing more.

Because of this, I'm assuming that you intend to show some information after the form is submitted. Here's a simple example that just displays an acknowledgement after the form is submitted.

```html
{% if submitted %}

    <div class="jumbotron contactainer">
        <h1 class="display-4">Submitted</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p class="lead">{{ username }}'s album has been submitted</p>
    </div>

{% else %}


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include 'form_template.html' %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def testing_Form(request):
    submit = False
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        form = MyOwnForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            album = form.save(commit=False)
            album.username = request.user
            album.save()
            submit = True 
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            return render(request, 'form.html', {'username':username, 'submitted':submit})
        else:
            return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form, 'submitted':submit})
```

You can do anything you wish with the `username` variable or add new variables, just remember to add them to the context dictionary if you wish to display them. The `submit` variable I've added is used in the template to determine what to show. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are exactly trying to achieve. However if you want to show the value of your previous submit on your screen for example as: `Previous submitted username: <input username>`, you can use the defined `form` in your template, including the values if there was a submit before.

```
{% if form.username.value %}
    Previous submitted username: {{ form.username.value }}
{%  endif %}

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {# ... all as it was ... #}
</form>
```

You can always add extra context to your template by assigning it to the context dictionary in the similar way you did with the `{'form': form}` as `{'form': form, 'hello': "My hello string"}` in your view.
In your template you could now use `{{ hello }}` as an variable.

Note that you are also using `commit=False` in your form to add more request data to the model after (`user`). Currently you left it in the `unsaved` state. To save the new form entry, you need to call `album.save()` after the modifications.

```
if form.is_valid():
    album = form.save(commit=False)
    album.user = request.user
    album.save() # now commit
```

The `username = form.cleaned_data['username']` has been defined, but never been used. Which with the example above is no longer required.

You can fetch the album objects when the user is authenticated and pass them to the template to work with as context like:
(bad practice style, but just to give you an idea within the scope of your code)

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
else:
    form = AlbumForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        album = form.save(commit=False)
        album.user = request.user

    albums = Album.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'formhandle/form.html', {'form': form, 'albums': albums})
```

Which you could show in your form template as:

```
{% if form.username.value %}
    Previous submitted username: {{ form.username.value }}
{%  endif %}

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {# ... all as it was ... #}
</form>

<ul>
    {% for album in albums %}
        <li>{{ album.user.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. I changed it on Nrzonline example.Is it also possible to save datas what is not asked in the form? Like Date or something?